# sqlite3.OperationalError: near ";": syntax error when Inserting

Tags: python, sqlite, character-encoding

I keep getting a sqlite3.OperationalError: near ";", can't figure out why...

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to insert records into a database from a list of employee tuples.

Have read other similar errors but not quite the same as this one.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("company.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()



cursor.execute("""DROP TABLE employee;""")

staff_data = [ ("William", "Shakespeare", "m", "19611025"),
("Frank", "Schiller", "m", "19550817"), ("Jane", "Wall", "f", "1989-03-14")]


# Define an SQL command
sql_command = """
CREATE TABLE employee (
staff_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
fname VARCHAR(20),
lname VARCHAR(30),
gender CHAR(1),
joining DATE,
birth_date DATE);
"""

# Execute command
cursor.execute(sql_command)

# Insert commands
sql_command = """ INSERT INTO employee (staff_number, fname, lname, gender,
birth_date) VALUES (NULL, "William", "Shakespeare", "m", "1961-10-25");"""

cursor.execute(sql_command)
print(sql_command)

for p in staff_data:
    format_str = """ INSERT INTO employee (staff_number, fname, lname, gender, birth_date) VALUES (NULL, "{first}", "{last}", "{gendera}", "{birthdate}"); """
    sql_command = format_str.format(first=p[0], last=p[1], gendera=p[2], birthdate=p[3])


print(sql_command)
cursor.execute(sql_command)



# DONT FORGET THIS TO SAVE CHANGES
connection.commit()

connection.close()
```

This is the error message:

```
 INSERT INTO employee (staff_number, fname, lname, gender,
birth_date) VALUES (NULL, "William", "Shakespeare", "m", "1961-10-25");
 INSERT INTO employee (staff_number, fname, lname, gender, birth_date) VALUES (NULL, "Jane", "Wall", "f", "1989-03-14"); 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqliteuse0.py", line 53, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql_command)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ";": syntax error
```

Comment: Which line is giving this error?

Comment: Also, you can't use double quotes inside a double quoted (`"""`) string.  You need to escape them or use single quotes.

Comment: Show the complete error message.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: what? `>>> """ a "b" c """` -> `' a "b" c '`

Comment: @JacobKrall: Oh?  I tested that in a shell and it didn't work.  Maybe I did something wrong.  You're right... never mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
    format_str = """ INSERT INTO employee (staff_number, fname, lname, gender, birth_date) VALUES (NULL, "{first}", "{last}", "{gendera}", "{birthdate}"); """
```

That's not a semicolon (`;`). It's [U+037E GREEK QUESTION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/037e/index.htm) (`;`).

Replace it with a semicolon and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I used difflib.ndiff to compare the typed string and the one generated by formatting and it said format_str had a missing ;. I deleted and retyped it and it solved the issue. I believe this was due to copying directly from a pdf with the example code.

Issue solved